# Can bosses bleed out in Escape from Tarkov?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

In Escape From Tarkov scav bots can be inflicted with health debuffs like the bleed or heavy bleed effect which can allow you to disengage a conflict and wait for your opponent to perish if they're unable to heal themselves.

Bosses have dramatically different stats, but I'm not sure if it's possible to inflict a heavy bleed effect on them. If I wound a boss with bullets that would normally cause a heavy bleed would I be able to hide from them and wait for them to bleed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, I have seen this happen on multiple occasions, with both *Shturman* and *Sanitar* - the latter being extra surprising because *Sanitar* is generally both well equipped and proficient in using medical items.

With both bosses, the kill was eventually attributed to a limb hit. The time passed between inflicting the wound and credited kill matched up with the expected time: their better-than-PMC health pool makes even heavy bleeds take longer to become threatening.

I believe I have positively confirmed **both bosses and boss followers** perishing this way though they still had the medical requisites to stop it in their backpack. We can expect this to become more difficult to pull off as soon as the AI is fixed concerning at least using up what they are carrying.

I have yet to confirm whether this is also possible with other [DoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_video_game_terms#Damage_over_time) mechanics such as

> the poisoned knife found from *cultist* NPCs (others [tried without success](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZJ5SLnD9co) so far).

<sub>Answered for version `0.12.11` - When trying to confirm whether this still happens in future versions of the game, ensure you really do see/hear the boss die. I suspect certain sources of damage (friendly fire grenades & ricochets) can be ignored when looking whom to attribute a kill to. Thus the post-game summary might imply the boss bled out, when in fact further damage sealed his fate.</sub>

Comment: I have not properly tested this yet, but this answer *may* be partly outdated, as there has been a patch note entry claiming a bug around using up carried medical items has been fixed.